# String formatting with concatenation

Tags: python

I am trying to concatenate the string and number with string formatting, but I am getting an error

> "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

This is my code

```
i = 0
while (i<= 10):
  print("insert into Member" + "(Mem_ID)")
  print("values" + "(" + "Mem%d" +  ")" %(i))
i = i+1
```

Comment: try: `print("values(Mem%d)" %(i))`....no `+`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you shouldn't be using Python's built-in string formatting to compose sql statements anyway. Whatever library you're using to execute the sql will have a feature to let you insert variables without the danger of sql injection attacks.

Comment: try `print("values(Mem%d)" %(i))`

Comment: @depperm it worked, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Kevin i am just using it for generating fake data that's all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how you are using %

The `%d` that is being replaced should have `%(var)` next to the quote.

```
i = 0
while (i<= 10):
    print("insert into Member " + "(Mem_ID)")
    print("values " + "(" + "Mem%d"%(i) +  ")" )
    i += 1
```

keep in mind you should be using `.format()` as the current method.

```
i = 0
while (i<= 10):
    print("insert into Member " + "(Mem_ID)")
    print("values " + "(" + "Mem{}".format(i) +  ")" )
    i += 1
```

Also to be clear some of your quotes are not needed. You can also use this.

```
i = 0
while (i<= 10):
    print("insert into Member (Mem_ID)")
    print("values (Mem{})".format(i))
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this much more simplier if you convert the int into a string like this:

```
i = 0
while (i<= 10):
    print("insert into Member " + "(Mem_ID)")
    print("values " + "(" + "Mem" + str(i) + ")")
    i = i+1
```

Comment: you have the same indentation problem as OP

Comment: Make sure you use proper indention when answering questions.

Comment: Indent `i = i+1` as well

Comment: My God... what's wrong with my eyes today... thanks to all of you pals!

Comment: lol. It happens. Trying to get that quick response in sometimes make you overlook the simple things.

Comment: Yes @SierrMountainTech By sure... absolutly right :)... You stole a hube smile from me hahaha :D

Comment: Thanks to you too @depperm, hope you are not trying to suicide after reading all of it haha.